# Select2 and Datepicker together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-select2

I have a jQuery datepicker that is going to be used for a history project, so it needs to be able to go back a long time. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/4wvF6/.

My datepicker:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  yearRange: '0:2013'
});
```

If you look at the dropdown, you can see its really long and takes a while if you wanted to get to say 1200 for the year. I looked at [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/), and it seems like a good way to make it easier to choose the years.

Is there a way I can override the jQuery datepicker and have it display a select2 dropdown instead of what it has now?

Comment: Something like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/4wvF6/1/

Comment: try press dropdown year and type 1200

Answer (score 0):

I use jquery ui datepicker that you have select box inside your datepicker, like this:

```
$(function() {
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
          timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt z',
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          showWeek: true,
          firstDay: 1,
          showAnim: 'slideDown',
          dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
          minDate: 0 ,


        });
```

[image]